# In which surah two time " bismillah" comes

Tags: quran, quran-recitation

In which surah two time "bismillah " comes
One time bismillah comes in starting and second time comes in middle .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In surah An__Naml "bismillah"comes 2 times  which is 27 surah of quran

Answer (score 1):

The complete phrase بِسْمِ اللهِ الرَّحْمٰنِ الرَّحِيْمِ 
appears within only one Surah, in An-Naml 30:

> Indeed, it is from Solomon, and indeed, it reads: 'In the name of Allah, the Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful,

Since every Surah except At-Tawbah starts is started with it, so you can say that it appears twice in Surah An-Naml.

Answer (score 0):

In Surat An-Naml bismillah comes twice